# Queries SQL - Sakila BD

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating some queries.
I'm using `Sakila DB`. I am trying to create a new column with the number of delays per client, using "`count ((datediff (rental.rental_date, rental.return_date))> film.rental_duration` as n"...

Which are the top 10 customers with the most delays in returning movies.

```
Select customer.first_name, customer.last_name, count ((datediff (rental.rental_date, rental.return_date))> film.rental_duration as nTime
From customer,film,rental,inventory  
Where customer.customer_id=rental.customer_id  
and rental.inventory_id=inventory.inventory_id   
and (datediff (rental.rental_date,rental.return_date)) > film.rental_duration
limit 10;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems you are missing JOIN queries (when you are working with multiple tables in a singe query)

Comment: Just curious, is there some book, tutorial, or website somewhere that presents this an acceptable way to join tables?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few assumptions, but this should be quite close to what you want:

```
select c.customer_id, count(*)
from 
    customer c
    inner join rental r 
        on r.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    inner join film f
        on f.film_id = r.film_id
        and (datediff (r.rental_date, r.return_date)) > f.rental_duration           
group by c.customer_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

Problems with your query:

- it is missing aggregation; you need to group records by customers, so you can compute how many late rental returns happened per customer
- it is missing a join condition for the `film` table; I assumed that `film` relates to `rental` through column `film_id`
- the previous issue would have been much more easier to spot if you were using standard, explicit joins instead of old-school, implicit joins; this is one of the many reasons why you should *always* use standard joins
- as commented by Thorsten Kettner, the `inventory` table seems superfluous in this query: the 3 other tables contain all the information you need

Comment: I like this answer, because of a well written query and explanation. The date comparision, however, belongs to the film's `ON` clause, not the inventory's. (Which makes me think that the inventory table is not needed at all in the query.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: ah yes, you are probably right. I removed the `inventory` table from the query.